# Add item to list with dynamic icon

Tags: react-native, icons

When user adds new data to the list I want to add icon dynamically(social icons commonly) in react native. For example,when user adds item that has name facebook then facebook icon should be added in background to the list(item name may be face,fcb etc) How can I achieve this logic ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague but I'm guessing you're looking for what's called "conditional rendering".

```
<View>
  {someCondition &&
    <FacebookIcon />
  }
</View>
```

The `FacebookIcon` component will only be rendered if `someCondition` is true.
So in your case, you probably wanna have a variable that is true or false based on whether your "list" contains the data you want, and use that variable to determine whether to show the icon.

If you want the icon to be dynamic (eg, be able to have Facebook, Insta, Whatsapp), you have another variable that holds the social network you've identified, and pass that as a prop to the icon component:

```
const listSocialNetwork = 'facebook' // or whatever you find in your list
const showIcon = !!listSocialNetwork // true if a social network was found in the list

// in your render

<View>
  {showIcon &&
    <SocialIcon socialNetwork={listSocialNetwork} />
  }

</View>
```